# estreamchat is missing Microsoft.Practices.Unity.resources.dll when enable Remote User Authentication Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

It was fine when I use default setting, but when I followed this instruction https://estreamchat.estreamdesk.com/forums/43879/topics/18421. I have found the problem.

I passed url as : `http://localhost:63416/ChatRoom.aspx?id=John&timestamp=130917100601&hash=0b72d6f1102f185508d7eed2c6a51e176a6eca20`

and it was saying that Microsoft.Practices.Unity.resources.dll is missing and I check the file from that path and it is really not existed.

How anyone has experience fixing this kind of problem? I cannot ask support question from that website, because it allows only licenced customers

Comment: I forget to update that I got thing working now.